# Blank line is not allowed in python functions?

Tags: python, syntax

(A) This works:

```
def func():
    x = 1
    print(x)    
    return
```

(B) This doesn't work:

```
def func():
    x = 1

    print(x)    
    return
```

(C) This also doesn't work: (Here I am using '_' to indicate a white space)

```
def func():
    x = 1
____
    print(x)    
    return
```

(D) This works:

```
def func():
    x = 1
____# some comment
    print(x)    
    return
```

In both (B) and (C) I get the following errors:

- NameError: name 'x' is not defined
- SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

I am using Eclipse and the PyDev plug-in. The Python version is 3.5 and the PyDev version is 4.5.

----------update----------

1. The issue is not reproducible in Jupyter Notebook and PyCharm.
2. In Eclipse I have turned on "Show whitespace characters". The indent in (C) is indeed composed of 4 whitespaces which are displayed as 4 dots in the editor. If it was a tab, in the Eclipse editor it would be displayed as ">>    ".

Given my through investigation and the comments/answers below, I am pretty sure this is a stupid bug of Eclipse and/or PyDev.

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Of course does (B) work in Python. The error will be elsewhere.

Comment: In my code I don't use _. I am using it in this question for clarity.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. You might have a mixture of tabs and spaces for your indentation?

Comment: You must have something wrong on your identation. (B) should work fine, anyways I just ran it and it works as expected

Comment: Are you pasting this into an interactive prompt?

Comment: @glibdud: No...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to your principal question: ***Blank line is not allowed in python functions?***

Blank line **is definitely allowed** in python functions.

All of yours examples (A,B,C,D) should work and the problem probably (sure) is related to *"Eclipse and the PyDev plug-in"*.

Consider migrating to another IDE like:

- Spyder - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyder
- PyCharm - https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

And consider using [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/) to help your development.

Answer (score 7):

be careful with tabs and spaces, they are not the same, so:

(_ are withe spaces)

```
def func():
____x = 1
____
____print(x)
____return
```

It will work just fine

is not the same as

(+ are tabs, _ white spaces)

```
def func():
++x = 1
__
++print(x)
++return
```

Won't work

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful information for anyone else who is new to Python like me. But this is not the cause of my problem. I'll vote up but will select the other one as the answer.